# Build Emacs with X support

Tags: emacs

I am trying to build Emacs 24.0.94 with X support on a 64-bit [SUSE Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux) (10.2 Enterprise release) box. I see that the X11 libraries are installed in /usr/lib/X11R6 and I am telling the configure script to look for them in that location:

```
--x-includes=/usr/X11R6/include:/usr/include --x-libraries=/usr/X11R6/lib64:/usr/lib64
```

Even with the above options, the configure script complains that it cannot find any X toolkit:

```
checking X11 version 6... before 6
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for librsvg-2.0 >= 2.11.0... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for Wand >= 6.2.8... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10 glib-2.0 >= 2.10... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for dbus-1 >= 1.0... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gio-2.0 >= 2.26... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gconf-2.0 >= 2.13... no
checking for lgetfilecon in -lselinux... no
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gnutls >= 2.6.6... no
checking for gnutls_certificate_set_verify_function... no
checking for xaw3d... no
checking for libXaw... configure: error: No X toolkit could be found.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without an X toolkit, pass
  --with-x-toolkit=no
to configure.  Otherwise, install the development libraries for the toolkit
that you want to use (e.g. Gtk+) and re-run configure.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which toolkit do you want to use? Do you have it properly installed? Where? If you don't know, you probably want to go with GTK.

Comment: Yes, X11 is the very lowest level of the display functionality. To draw a parallel with Windows, think of it as the bits of functionality needed to handle graphics card drivers and to paint blobs on screen. On top of that layer, you need something that provides libraries for buttons and menus and all the other stuff that goes into a graphical application, and you're missing that piece. Gtk+ is probably the one you want, so as others have said, just install gtk2-devel (or whatever it's called?) and the build should work.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comment below about local install of emacs/gtk2-devel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On SUSE Linux you will typically want to compile Emacs with support for GTK, so you should install GTK headers along with X headers (package `gtk2-devel`).

In order to compile Emacs with all modern features you will want to install development packages for packages not found in your `./configure` output: rsvg, dbus, gnutls, etc...

Comment: Thanks. I am doing a local install(installing emacs in my home directory) as I do not have sudo/root privileges on the system. Is it possible to install the gtk2-devel package locally and use that for building emacs?

Comment: @Raj Try to download the RPM and and install it locally. [Here are some instruction](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/rpm-installation-having-no-root-access-762363/), but I didn't test them.

Comment: @Antoine probably has the easier solution, but you can also download the Gtk+ source code and install it the same way ("./configure --prefix=/home/Raj/local"). The upside of using RPM is that it should handle dependencies for you. With source, you'll have to make sure you install any required libraries on your own. Either way, you'll probably need to tell the configure script for emacs where the libraries are installed, so something like "./configure --prefix=/home/Raj/local --with-gtk=/home/Raj/local". Read the configure help to get the flags right.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I decided to install emacs without X.

Answer (score 15):

Since like last week you can now compile with GTK3.

Here is the list of dependencies for [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)-based systems:

- Tools:

  gcc autoconf automake texinfo libtool git
- libraries:

  libncurses5-dev libgnutls-dev librsvg2-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff-dev libgif-dev libqt4-dev libgtk-3-dev

  (another way is to use `apt-get build-dep emacs23` and add `gtk3`)

And here is the script I use for automated builds on all my machines:

```
#!/bin/bash

init=false
SRC_DIR=~/src

if [ ! -d "$SRC_DIR" ]; then mkdir $SRC_DIR; fi

if [ ! -d "$SRC_DIR/emacs" ]; then
    init=true
    cd $SRC_DIR && pwd && git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/emacs.git && cd emacs
else
    cd $SRC_DIR/emacs
fi

git pull 1>&1 | grep "Already up-to-date."
if [[ ! $? -eq 0 && ! $init ]]; then
    read -e -p "## Branch moved, build and install emacs? [Y/n] " yn
    if [[ $yn == "y" || $yn == "Y" || $yn == "" ]] ; then
          make distclean && autoreconf -i -I m4 && ./configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk3 && make && sudo make install
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You're welcome, Raj. It could be better ; I don't like how I'm forced to grep the output of git to determine if the branch has moved.