# How can I compile and install Emacs in the home directory?

Tags: linux, emacs, configure

I want to install Emacs without using [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software))/[YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified), because I am not a super user.

I downloaded the source code from
*https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Installing-Emacs.html*. Then, I commanded

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local/emacs/27_1
```

Standard output said

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
     gnutls
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
To build anyway, give:
     --with-gnutls=ifavailable
as options to configure.
```

So I commanded

```
./configure --with-gnutls=ifavailable --prefix=$HOME/.local/emacs/27_1
```

Standard output said

```
configure: error: The required function 'tputs' was not found in any library.
The following libraries were tried (in order):
  libtinfo, libncurses, libterminfo, libcurses, libtermcap
Please try installing whichever of these libraries is most appropriate
for your system, together with its header files.
For example, a libncurses-dev(el) or similar package.
```

So I downloaded ncurses and installed it by:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz ncurses-6.2.tar.gz
cd ncurses-6.2
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local/ncurses/6_2 --with-shared --with-pkg-config-libdir=$HOME/ncurses/6_2/lib/pkgconfig --enable-pc-files
make
make install
```

And I made symbolic links and PATH

```
cd ~/.local/bin
ls ../ncurses/6_2/bin/ | xargs -I {} ln -s ../ncurses/6_2/bin/{} {}
cd ~/.local/include
ls ../ncurses/6_2/include/ | xargs -I {} ln -s ../ncurses/6_2/include/{} {}
cd ~/.local/lib
ls ../ncurses/6_2/lib/ | xargs -I {} ln -s ../ncurses/6_2/lib/{} {}
cd ~/.local/lib/pkgconfig
ls ../../ncurses/6_2/lib/pkgconfig/ | xargs -I {} ln -s ../../ncurses/6_2/lib/pkgconfig/{} {}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/.local/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:$HOME/.local/lib/pkgconfig
```

I did configure again, but the same error occurred. What should I do?

Comment: On what platform? Ubuntu? What is the installation history, e.g. for development tools (if any)?

Comment: I tried the same thing today on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 (using http://ftp.download-by.net/gnu/gnu/emacs/emacs-27.1.tar.gz) and got similar errors.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` first?

Comment: The `tputs` error was overcome in [this blog post](https://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2012/06/installing-emacs-241.html). It is from 2012 and I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: OK, I managed to do it on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)). I wrote a blog post about it, with step-by-step instructions that should be able to be followed blindly and get it to work: *[Building Emacs from source on Ubuntu 20.04](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/11/11/building-emacs-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04/)*

Comment: Related (not duplicates): *[Build Emacs with X support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678189)* and *[Build Emacs on Ubuntu - libraries not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297581)*